# Handling transaction with UnitOfWork and EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 and MVC4. I have couple of domains. Each of them has its own DbContext (which uses appropriate tables), repository and service. I also implemented UnitOfWork.

Handling specific flow in transaction inside one service for specific domain is simple. I'm doing some operations on tables and at the end I'm invoking UnitOfWork.Save, which behaves as Transaction.Commit.

But lets assume I have a case in which I have to invoke operations for two different domains and this two operations must be put inside one transaction. I have access to services for domains from controller so this actions are invoked from there. At the moment I can see three solutions:

1. I must have UnitOfWork in controller and call Save method at the end (I don't like this idea).
2. Create some service in which I will have UnitOfWork and access to both services (actually it is the same solution as above, but I'm moving logic to separate class)
3. I have to create additional TransactionScope inside controller and commit it at the end

Please let me know what option you think is the best. If you have any other than the three above, let me know. Or maybe something is wrong with my concept? I mean domains and their db contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your UnitOfWork implementation supports normal Transactions in .NET, you can do the following and they should enroll in the currently running transaction.

```
protected TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
{
    var options = new TransactionOptions();
    options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    options.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
    return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options);
}

using (var scope = this.CreateTransactionScope())
{
    // do operations with context 1
    // do operations with context 2

    scope.Complete();
}
```